# Java - Player array from class

Tags: java, arrays, class

What I need to do is to be able to call the Player array in my view class, print whose turn it is and their score. When their turn is over, move on to the next player and print that players score. When it goes back to being player 1's turn, it brings back their total score and adds on to that.

The end goal:
Player and Die class are an array. My die and scoring methods are pretty good. This is the game of greed/farkle. 1 player rolls 6 die, and gets a score based off of those. The unused/unscored die are then rolled. At the end of the players turn, we must print out their turn score and total score. Move on to the next player, and do it all over again. When a certain player hits a certain score, the game is over and that person is the winner.

Right now I only have an if statement that cycles through 4 players. This isn't the objective. I need to get the player class into an array, and use that class to cycle through players, and possibly use it to report their game score.

```
public class Player {

/** player id */
private int id;

/** player name */
private String name;

/** player's score in the game */
private int gameScore;  

/**
 * Constructs a new Player with the specified id.
 * 
 * @param id player's id
 */
public Player(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * Returns the id of player.
 * 
 * @return player's id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * Returns the name of player.
 * 
 * @return player's name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * Sets the name of player using the given parameter value.
 * 
 * @param name value used to set the name of player
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Returns the player's score in the game.
 * 
 * @return player's score in the game
 */
public int getGameScore() {
    return gameScore;
}

/**
 * Sets the game score of a player.
 * 
 * @param score value used to set the game score of player
 */
public void setGameScore(int score) {
    this.gameScore = score;
}

/**
 * Returns a String representing a player.
 * 
 * @return string form of this player
 */
public String toString() {
    return id + "";
}
```

}

```
public class Die {

/** maximum face value */
private static final int MAX = 6;

/** current value showing on the die */
private int faceValue;

/**
 * Constructs a Die instance with a face value of 1.
 */
public Die() {
    faceValue = 1;
}

/**
 * Computes a new face value for this die and returns the result.
 * 
 * @return face value of die
 */
public int roll() {
    faceValue = (int) (Math.random() * MAX) + 1;
    return faceValue;
}

/**
 * Sets the face value of the die.
 * 
 * @param value an int indicating the face value of the die
 */
public void setFaceValue(int value) {
    if (value > 0 && value <= MAX) {
        faceValue = value;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the face value of the die.
 * 
 * @return the face value
 */
public int getFaceValue() {
    return faceValue;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.*;

import model.Die;
import model.Player;
import model.GreedGame;

public class GreedCLI {

private int whoInt;
private int farkleScore;
private Player playerClass;
private GreedGame farkle;
private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private final int max = 4;
private final int min = 2;
private final int minStarter = 1;
private final int minScore = 1000;
private final int maxScore = 10000;
int toWin, totalPlayers, player;
public GreedCLI() {
    startUp();
    gameOn();
}

public void startUp() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Farkle! \n \n");

    totalPlayers = getPlayerTotal("Please enter total number of player (2-4): ");
    toWin = getScoreTotal("Please enter total points needed to win: ");
    player = getStartPlayer();

    System.out.println("\nGood Luck!\n");
    farkle = new GreedGame(totalPlayers, player, toWin);
}

private int getStartPlayer() {
    int who;
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Which player will start the game(1-"
                    + totalPlayers + ")?: ");
            who = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            if (who < minStarter || who > totalPlayers) {
                System.out.println("Error - values outside parameter.");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            scan.next();
            System.out.println("Error - input must be an integer value.");
        }
    }
    return who;
}

private int getPlayerTotal(String enter) {
    int playerTotal;
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(enter + "");
            playerTotal = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            if (playerTotal < min || playerTotal > max) {
                System.out.println("Error - values outside parameter.");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            scan.next();
            System.out.println("Error - input must be an integer value.");
        }
    }
    return playerTotal;
}

private int getScoreTotal(String enter) {
    int scoreTotal;
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(enter + "");
            scoreTotal = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            if (scoreTotal < minScore || scoreTotal > maxScore) {
                System.out.println("Error - values outside parameter.");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            scan.next();
            System.out.println("Error - input must be an integer value.");
        }
    }
    return scoreTotal;
}

//  public int scoreTotal() {
//      int playerScore = playerClass.getGameScore() + farkleScore;
//      return playerScore;
//  }

private void gameOn() {
    boolean over = false;
    boolean endTurn = false;
    String answer;
    char answerChar = 'Y';

    String roll;

    System.out.println("Player " + farkle.getPlayers() + "'s turn!");

    while (!over) {

        while (!endTurn) {
            roll = farkle.toString();
            farkleScore = farkle.score();
            System.out.println("Player " + farkle.getPlayers() + " rolls "
                    + roll + " worth " + farkleScore);

            if (farkleScore < 1) {
                System.out
                        .println("Sorry, you rolled a 0. Moving on to the next Player!");
                endTurn = true;
            }
            if (farkle.availableDie() < 1) {
                System.out
                        .println("Sorry, you are out of dice. Moving on to the next Player!");
                endTurn = true;
            }
            if (farkle.availableDie() > 1 && farkleScore > 1) {
                System.out
                        .print("Would you like to keep rolling? You have "
                                + farkle.availableDie()
                                + " die remaining (Y or N): ");
                answer = scan.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
                answerChar = answer.charAt(0);
                if (answerChar == 'N') {
                    endTurn = true;
                }
            }

        }
        while (endTurn) {
            System.out.println("\nNow it is the next player's turn.");
            farkle.passDie();
            farkle.nextPlayer();
            endTurn = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GreedCLI();
}
```

}

```
package model;

import java.util.*;

public class GreedGame {

/** int for total die remaining */
private int remainingDie = 6;

/** counts number of times number appears */
private int[] numFreq;

/** array for players */
private int players = 1;

/** call player class */
private Player playerFromClass;

/** array for die */
private int[] die;


private Player[] who;
private int whoInt;

/** total players */
private int totalPlayers;

/** starting player */
private int currentPlayer;

/** total number of points needed */
private int winningPoints;

/** calls player method to get turn */
private Player turn;

/** score for the turn */
private int turnScore = 0;

/** score for the turn */
private int totalScore;

/** string for the roll result for the toString */
private String rollResult;

/** calls class to roll the die */
Die dieRoll = new Die();


/*****************************************************************
 * Default constructor, sets the values of the instance variables
 * 
 * @param players
 *            and winning points pulled from CLI
 *****************************************************************/

public GreedGame(int totalPlayers, int firstPlayer, int winningPoints) {
    super();
    this.totalPlayers = totalPlayers;
    this.currentPlayer = firstPlayer;
    this.winningPoints = winningPoints;
}

public Player playerClass() {
    return playerFromClass;
}

public int getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

/*  private Player[] getStartPlayerClass() {
    for(int i = 0; i < totalPlayers; i++){
        i = this.currentPlayer++;
    }
    return who;
}*/

public void nextPlayer(){
    if(players < 1){
        players = 1;
    }
    else if(players < 4){
        players++;
    }
    else{
        players = 1;
    }
}

/*private int getStartPlayerInt(){
    whoInt = who.getId();
    return whoInt;
}*/

public Player getTurn(){
    return turn;
}

public void setPlayers(int players) {
    this.players = players;
}

/*****************************************************************
 * calculates remaining die
 *****************************************************************/

public int availableDie() {
    return this.remainingDie;
}

/*****************************************************************
 * boolean to passDie
 *****************************************************************/

public void passDie() {
    this.remainingDie = 6;
}

/*****************************************************************
 * array to roll the remaining dice
 *****************************************************************/

public int[] rollDie() {
    this.die = new int[this.remainingDie];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.die.length; i++) {
        this.die[i] = dieRoll.roll();
    }

    return this.die;
}

/*****************************************************************
 * toString for the cli to call, puts roll in string.
 *****************************************************************/

public String toString() {
    rollResult = Arrays.toString(rollDie());
    return rollResult;
}

/*****************************************************************
 * score method to add up total points and can be called elsewhere
 *****************************************************************/

public int score() {
    rollCheck();
    turnScore = 0;
    return straight() + threePairs() + sixOfAKind() + fiveOfAKind()
            + fourOfAKind() + threeOfAKind() + eachFive() + eachOne();
}

/*****************************************************************
 * array to roll the remaining dice
 *****************************************************************/

public int[] rollCheck() {
    availableDie();
    this.numFreq = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // set to zero
        this.numFreq[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.remainingDie; i++) {

        if (die[i] == 1) {
            numFreq[0] += 1;
        }
        if (die[i] == 2) {
            numFreq[1] += 1;
        }
        if (die[i] == 3) {
            numFreq[2] += 1;
        }
        if (die[i] == 4) {
            numFreq[3] += 1;
        }
        if (die[i] == 5) {
            numFreq[4] += 1;
        }
        if (die[i] == 6) {
            numFreq[5] += 1;
        }
    }
    return this.numFreq;
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling a single or two 1's
 *****************************************************************/
private int eachOne() {

    if (straight() == 0 && sixOfAKind() == 0 && threePairs() == 0
            && this.numFreq[0] < 3) {
        if (this.numFreq[0] == 1) {
            turnScore = 100;
            this.remainingDie--;
            return turnScore;
        }else if (this.numFreq[0] == 2) {
            turnScore = 200;
            this.remainingDie -= 2;
            return turnScore;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling a single or two 5's
 *****************************************************************/

private int eachFive() {

    if (straight() == 0 && sixOfAKind() == 0 && threePairs() == 0
            && this.numFreq[4] < 3) {
        if (this.numFreq[4] == 1) {
            turnScore = 50;
            this.remainingDie--;
            return turnScore;
        }else if (this.numFreq[4] == 2) {
            turnScore = 100;
            this.remainingDie -= 2;
            return turnScore;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling 3 of a kind
 *****************************************************************/
private int threeOfAKind() {

    if (sixOfAKind() == 0 && fiveOfAKind() == 0 && fourOfAKind() == 0
            && straight() == 0) {
        if (this.numFreq[0] == 3) {
            turnScore += 1000;
            this.remainingDie -= 3;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[1] == 3) {
            turnScore += 200;
            this.remainingDie -= 3;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[2] == 3) {
            turnScore += 300;
            this.remainingDie -= 3;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[3] == 3) {
            turnScore += 400;
            this.remainingDie -= 3;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[4] == 3) {
            turnScore += 500;
            this.remainingDie -= 3;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[5] == 3) {
            turnScore += 600;
            this.remainingDie -= 3;
            return turnScore;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling four of a kind
 *****************************************************************/
private int fourOfAKind() {

    if (sixOfAKind() == 0 && fiveOfAKind() == 0 && straight() == 0) {
        if (this.numFreq[0] == 4) {
            turnScore += 2000;
            this.remainingDie -= 4;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[1] == 4) {
            turnScore += 400;
            this.remainingDie -= 4;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[2] == 4) {
            turnScore += 600;
            this.remainingDie -= 4;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[3] == 4) {
            turnScore += 800;
            this.remainingDie -= 4;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[4] == 4) {
            turnScore += 1000;
            this.remainingDie -= 4;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[5] == 4) {
            turnScore += 1200;
            this.remainingDie -= 4;
            return turnScore;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling 5 of a kind
 *****************************************************************/
private int fiveOfAKind() {

    if (sixOfAKind() == 0 && straight() == 0) {
        if (this.numFreq[0] == 5) {
            turnScore += 4000;
            this.remainingDie -= 5;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[1] == 5) {
            turnScore += 800;
            this.remainingDie -= 5;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[2] == 5) {
            turnScore += 1200;
            this.remainingDie -= 5;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[3] == 5) {
            turnScore += 1600;
            this.remainingDie -= 5;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[4] == 5) {
            turnScore += 2000;
            this.remainingDie -= 5;
            return turnScore;
        }
        if (this.numFreq[5] == 5) {
            turnScore += 2400;
            this.remainingDie -= 5;
            return turnScore;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling 6 of a kind
 *****************************************************************/
private int sixOfAKind() {

    if (this.numFreq[0] == 6) {
        turnScore += 8000;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[1] == 6) {
        turnScore += 1600;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[2] == 6) {
        turnScore += 2400;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[3] == 6) {
        turnScore += 3200;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[4] == 6) {
        turnScore += 4000;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[5] == 6) {
        turnScore += 4800;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling 3 pairs
 *****************************************************************/
private int threePairs() {
    int pairs = 0;
    if (this.numFreq[0] == 2) {
        pairs++;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[1] == 2) {
        pairs++;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[2] == 2) {
        pairs++;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[3] == 2) {
        pairs++;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[4] == 2) {
        pairs++;
    }
    if (this.numFreq[5] == 2) {
        pairs++;
    }
    if (pairs == 3) {
        turnScore += 800;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * scoring method for rolling a straight
 *****************************************************************/
private int straight() {
    if (this.numFreq[0] == 1 && this.numFreq[1] == 1
            && this.numFreq[2] == 1 && this.numFreq[3] == 1
            && this.numFreq[4] == 1 && this.numFreq[5] == 1) {
        turnScore += 1200;
        this.remainingDie -= 6;
        return turnScore;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: -If this is just a matter of using a datastructure to keep a list and loop through the list look at Java Collection or define an array. You can decouple the loop index from the for loop and increment it conditionally. You can also call methods within the for loop or add logic that needs to before the next player is set.

Comment: FYI the `player` tag does not pertain to a "Player" class.

Comment: What I figured I would do is setup a for loop that takes in input of int, increments that player to the next number, and returns that number. But I can't return an int, needs to be a Player object, and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do, So correct me if this isn't what you need, but to make an array of type `Player` of size `n` you'd do something like the following

```
Player[] playerArray = new Player[n];

for(int i=0; i<playerArray.length; i++)
{
    // If you need your player id to be different than i just say so in the comments
    playerArray[i] = new Player(i);
}
```

and that's just about it.

I have a sneaky suspicion that your requirements are a little more  complex than that, but It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for, so if you need something different, just say so.

Comment: Yea sorry, I updated my post with a clear goal that needs to be accomplished.

Comment: I have an instance variable "private Player[] who;"

Comment: @Enormosaurus Why don't I see that instance variable anywhere in the code you've posted?

Comment: I am calling Player class in my own model class. Player is given by my professor, and we integrate it into our own class. We can't edit Player class.

Comment: @Enormosaurus can you please edit your question and add your own code to it?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want the application to wait untill a player made a move, then go on to the next player?

You'll have to write an event playerMoved.  When that event happens, you manually increase your index and wait for the next player to make a move.